# How do I locate abnormal sounds in my water pipes?

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure

I've noticed that my water pipes have started making an interesting sound. It's not all the time but it seems like its 50/50 at this point. Below are a couple videos to help illustrate what is going on:

- [Video of normal water pipe sounds](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/02U_YeRByBs)
- [Video of abnormal water pipe sounds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dc9Gu1XUIk4)

I'm concerned there is a problem but I have no idea what it could be. How do I go about identifying the source of these sounds?

Comment: Have you tried correlating it with the use of particular fixtures? How about different flow rates? These are copper pipes?

Comment: I've tried establishing correlations but the noise is still hit and miss. I haven't attempted different flow rates but there may be something to that, I notice it more with toilets refilling and showers. Copper pipes yes - the home was built in the 70's and I believe the water from the city is coming in at about 120psi.

Comment: 120psi! Holy geez. Are you somewhat confident in that 120 psi? Are you in the US? That's a big number for household water pressure.

Comment: @popham Yes, in the US and please excuse me if my information isn't 100% correct. From what I have HEARD there's 120 coming in from the street and somewhere at the entry point to the house it's throttled down, i suspect to 80 if not less. [I found this image which conceptualizes it pretty well.](https://inspectapedia.com/plumbing/1507s.jpg)

Comment: Is this in a particular room?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever the flow of water turns a pipe corner, the change in momentum requires a force from the pipe. My expectation is that 2 unrestrained corners have dumb-lucked upon a resonant frequency of the pipe system between them. You've already found the system between them probably (that's where the noise is coming from), so to shut it up, you would cut yourself access in a few locations and restrain the pipe to eliminate the resonant frequency.

Less invasively, you could try sneaking a water hammer arrester into the system at some point, but that's only a *possible* solution. It's likelihood of success would depend on how close it is to the vibration. If you also have water hammer issues, though, then the arrester should be step one.

Comment: I took out an old water softener and the sound is MUCH worse. All signs point to a water hammer so I'm changing this to the accepted answer.

Comment: After repeatedly bleeding the pipes and trouble shooting the psi in the home this issue is resolved. My best assumption is a combination of trapped air and 80+psi. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

your abnormal vid sounds like a bad toilet fill valve.  you need to open various other faucets that give a smooth flow of water and see if the sound always persists.

Per your comment you **believe** the water pressure coming into the house is 120 psi.  I interpret that kind of statement as you don't actually know.  While 120 psi is not bad, until you actually measure you don't really know.  But for toilet valves higher water pressure at 90-120psi will make them much noisier than water pressure that is down around 60 psi when they all eventually go bad and becomes noisy.  And that noise can travel.  And that noise can be pretty interesting sometimes.

you can pick up a 0-200 psi pressure gauge at depot/lowes or get from amazon, and if it doesn't come with a hose thread fitting you have to rig one up, easiest way is to thread on the outdoor spigot and measure household pressure.

[CARBO Instruments 2-1/2" Pressure Gauge,Water Pressure Test Gauge, 3/4" Female Hose Thread, 0-200 PSI with Red Pointer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PGXSWF5): $10

Comment: It appears that I have TWO bad toilets, which helps explain why I get a mixture of normal and abnormal sounds that made it hard to track down the issue(s) with typical trial-and-error troubleshooting.